# What event can I use to to target elements on close of fancybox (lightbox mod)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

So I have a website using the fancybox plug-in (http://fancybox.net/).  I want the text inside of fancybox to be printable, so I wrote a function that sets everything but the elements in fancybox to have a display:none.  Here's my function:

```
var everything = [];
var hideEreythang = function () {
var everything = document.querySelectorAll(':not(.fancybox-opened):not(body):not(html):not(#shervani)');
var i = 0;
while (everything) {
    everything[i].style.display = "none";
    i++;
}
}
```

Problem is, once you close fancybox everything is still set to display:none.  Is there an event handler I can use that will be triggered by the close of fancybox (either by clicking the x button or clicking outside the box), so I can reset everything back to normal?  I'm still pretty new at js; I know fancybox has something that does that (since it's how theirs works) so I went through their source but had no idea what to look for.  It seems pretty complicated.  Is there a way I could manage to do this?

Thanks a million.

By the way, I'm using an onClick to run this function (the same link they click to open the fancybox)

EDIT: I think I'm just going to have it load two stylesheets, once for when they click on fancybox and (the normal one) when they close fancybox.  How (and where) do I put my onClose to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

In order to do something when fancybox was closed you can use [`onClosed`](http://fancybox.net/api) event

> onClosed: Will be called once FancyBox is closed

**Sample**

```
$("#tip5").fancybox({
    'onClosed': function() {
       // your logic
    }
});
```

Comment: so would i apply that to the same link used to open fancybox?  so <a onClick=hideEreythang() onClose=restoreStuff()> ?

Comment: @user3899791: `onClosed` handled is specified when you call `fancybox`. You should do it there.

Comment: i'm confused - where is there?

Comment: @user3899791: aren't you calling `.fancybox(...)` somewhere?